# Autofac Type access exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I'm trying to set up Autofac with MVC 5 and Web API 2 but I keep getting this error at runtime:

https://gyazo.com/b29dfb41431684f1b61d0fdd1c359765

I have no clue where to start looking for a potential fix.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full exception message, stack trace and appropriate details *into* your question. If you're interested into getting an answer, don't make a screen-shot of the error, and especially don't link to an image that is stored somewhere else.

Comment: It would also be good to provide details on the app itself - your packages.config, the code that runs when the exception gets thrown, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version problem. You are probably using the wrong version of Autofac.Integration.Mvc (maybe the one for MVC3 or MVC4).

First remove **all** references to Autofac.MVC you have in your solution.

Then install Autofac ASP.NET MVC 5 Integration running the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Autofac.Mvc5
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I ended up making another web project and it worked, was most likely indeed a version problem so i'll mark as answer , thanks :)